# Boyer-Moore Galil Rule

Tags: algorithm, substring

I was implementing the [Boyer-Moore Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer%E2%80%93Moore_string_search_algorithm) for substring search in Python when I learned about the [Galil Rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer%E2%80%93Moore_string_search_algorithm#The_Galil_Rule). I've looked around online for the Galil Rule but I haven't found anything more than a couple of sentences, and I cannot get access to the original paper. How can I implement this into my current algorithm?

```
i = 0
while i < (N - M + 1):
    skip = 0
    for j in reversed(range(0, M)):
        if pattern[j] != text[i + j]:
            skip = max(1, j - offsets[text[i+j]])
            break
    if skip == 0:
        return i
    i += skip
return -1
```

Notes:

- offsets[c] = -1 if c is not in the pattern
- offsets[c] = last index of c in the pattern

Example:
aaabcb

- offsets[a] = 2
- offsets[b] = 5
- offsets[c] = 4
- offsets[d] = -1

The few sentences I have found have said to keep track of when the first mismatch occurs in my inner loop (j, if the if-statement inside the inner loop is True) and the position in which I started the comparisons (i + j, in my case). I understand the intuition that I've already checked all the indices in between those, so I shouldn't have to do those comparisons again. I just don't understand how to connect the dots and arrive at an implementation.

Comment: http://thirdworld.nl/on-improving-the-worst-case-running-time-of-the-boyer-moore-string-matching-algorithm

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Galil rule is about exploiting periodicity in the pattern to reduce comparisons. Say you have a pattern `abcabcab`. It's periodic with smallest period `abc`. In general, a pattern `P` is periodic if there's a string `U` such that `P` is a prefix of `UUUUU...`. (In the above example, `abcabcab` is clearly a prefix of the repeating string `abc` = `U`.) We call the shortest such string the period of `P`. Let the length of that period be `k` (in the example above `k = 3` since `U = abc`).

First of all, keep in mind that the Galil rule applies *only* after you've found an occurrence of `P` in the text. When you do that, the Galil rule says that you could shift by `k` (the periodicity of the pattern) and you only have to compare the last `k` characters of the now shifted pattern to determine if there was a match.

Here's an example:

```
P = ababa
T = bababababab
U = ab
k = 2
```

First occurrence: `b[ababa]babab`. Now you can shift by `k = 2` and you only have to check the last two characters of the pattern:

```
T = bababa[ba]bab
P =    aba[ba]       // Only need to compare chars inside brackets for next match.
```

The rest of `P` *must* match since P is periodic and you shifted it by its period `k` *from an existing match* (this is crucial) so the repeating parts will nicely line up.

If you've found another match, just repeat. If you find a mismatch, however, you revert to the standard Boyer-Moore algorithm until you find another match. Remember, you can only use the Galil rule when you find a match *and* you shift by `k` (otherwise the pattern is not guaranteed to line up with the previous occurrence).

Now, you might wonder, how to determine `k` for a given pattern `P`. You'll need to calculate the suffixes array `N` first, where `N[i]` will be the length of the longest common suffix of the prefix `P[0, i]` and `P`. (You can calculate the suffixes array by calculating the prefixes array `Z` on the *reverse* of `P` using the Z algorithm, as described [here](https://ivanyu.me/blog/2013/10/15/z-algorithm/), for example.) Once you have the suffixes array, you can easily find `k` since it'll be the smallest `k > 0` such that `N[m - k - 1] == m - k` (where `m = |P|`).

For example:

```
P = ababa
m = 5
N = [1, 0, 3, 0, 5]
k = 2  because  N[m - k - 1] == N[5 - 2 - 1] == N[2] == 3 == 5 - k
```

Answer (score 2):

The answer by @Lajos Nagy has explained the idea of Galil rule perfectly, however we have a more straightforward way to calculate `k`:

**Just use the prefix function of KMP algorithm.**

The `prefix[i]` means the longest proper prefix of `P[0..i]` which is also a suffix.

And, `k = m-prefix[m-1]` .

[This article has explained the details.](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-given-string-can-represented-substring-iterating-substring-n-times/)